# Can't disable Windows search

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I'm trying to shut down Windows search, i.e. disable indexing.

I tried to change it to manual or disabled, but after I restarted the service it is still switched on. I have an SSD, so I don't want it to be enabled.

Comment: I'm not crazy. In google I spent half a day that I found. This procedure does not work. After start to run again and set to enabled.

Comment: So when you uninstall the search service it's still installed?

Comment: I can not install it. What I should start searching. I want to block indexing. Not uninstall it.

Comment: @nordic Go to my computer, right click C, and uncheck "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed... click OK, let it work, then restart.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the search indexing service, follow subsequent steps

1. Click start -> services.msc
2. Locate **Windows Search**
3. Double click and change **Startup type** to **Disabled**. Click ok.
4. Reboot your system and repeat steps #1 and #2 and confirm that the status field is blank (indicates that the service is not running).

To disable search, follow the instructions mentioned below

1. Click Start -> appwiz.cpl
2. Click Turn Windows features on or off
3. Untick Windows search from the list and click Yes
4. Click ok and restart

Instructions from http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/

Comment: This I have tried many times, but after restart it is again turned on.

Comment: Try this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/

Comment: +1 nice one R, good find, please add to your answer

Comment: yeah same over at [so], we dont like link rot. Bibliograhies are always welcome though.

Comment: It's useful to know that linking is not encouraged. I'm new here. However, I will not expand the solution at this juncture as the OP does not seem to be interested in uninstalling the search feature. Cheers for the feedback though.

Comment: Answers consisting solely of links are not encouraged. If the relevant steps are included here, on-site, it's okay though. @ta.speot.is "Use Google" as answers aren't welcome, but obscuring "Let Me Google That For You" links in URL shorteners is not encouraged either. It's rude and offensive.

Comment: use searchmyfiles app when you want to search something after disabling windows search...

Comment: For windows 10 users there is no longer any way to remove the feature using `appwiz.cpl`